# Azure Cognitive Search: Open PDF and highlight text

Tags: pdf, azure-cognitive-search, azure-search-.net-sdk

I have multiple PDFs in a blob storage and Azure cognitive search is applied on this blob storage. When 
searched is performed, it'll return the result with PDF filename and other related meta-data.

Now my requirement is to:

1. Open the PDF in which match is found.
2. Go to specific page number where searched is matched
3. Highlight the matched text.

Answer (score 1):

the solution already developed by Microsoft 
https://jfk-demo.azurewebsites.net/#/ 
https://github.com/microsoft/AzureSearch_JFK_Files

if you know react us and azure search with cognitive skill it is easy to understand.

using OCR cognitive skill, I have extract search text and location (x,y) of page.